# Detecting repeated records and marking old ones with the new record ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm clueless with the new requirement. To be honest I haven't coded anything yet so I'm asking you to help me only with the logic.

I have large table used for reports, this contains data from workers and in which periods they've worked (so we could have a lot of `ID01 John Doe Working From X to Y in Z`), this table gets constantly updated by who knows who but no one checks updated data (because sometimes `John Doe` worked actually from `X1 to Y2` instead of `X to Y`), so the requirement it's detecting duplicates on this table. So far I haven't found anything duplicated but I have to be one step ahead of this guy. Ok, do a trigger after insert you might say, and I did!. Presenting the solution to my boss he disliked it right away because he (currently) wants to work with a stored procedure on the current table so we could study cases where inserts match with old records, so I'll need to do it on what he wants I guess.

Here's the trigger anyway, if a duplicated row is entered, it changes the old value to 0 on VALIDO, a column I created to do something similar on new inserts (the trigger below it's not working properly though):

```
AS
IF EXISTS(
  SELECT 1
  FROM tstSolap t 
  INNER JOIN INSERTED i 
    ON t.ID_HR = i.ID_HR AND t.PERPRO = i.PERPRO
)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'duplicado'
    UPDATE tstSolap SET valido = 0
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    UPDATE tstSolap SET valido = 1
END
```

My question then it's how can I detect logically duplicated rows based on multiple criteria and setting one special column with the new ID? (so it's easier to detect manually)

Comment: Who is "this guy" you are referencing? You boss probably disliked it because this isn't a great use of a trigger. Instead, you should add a `constraint` and prevent duplicates from ever happening :) or handle this logic during insert, aka as an `UPSERT` where you update some records and insert others.

Comment: Trigger after insert will lower insert speed.
You say, that your table is used for reports, so there is sql, that gathers data for that reports.
I suppose, you can create view on your table, which will select distinct all you columns, and set that report to get data from this view instead of table.

Or you can also create procedure, that will delete duplicates and run it every ... hours (or minutes) with Sql Server Agent.

Or you can create procedure, that will incrementally gather data from your table to another table (Data Mart for your report), excluding duplicates.

Comment: @scsimon The guy who inserts data into the table. I need every data (old and new) on this table to study cases where the employee got his data so constraints and upserts won't work on this case.

Comment: @AlexSham The problem it's detecting new and old cases **on the same table**, so I'll have to set a column for that and when a duplicate exist set both old and new records "highlighted" (maybe inserting new record id on that column). A view with data splitted wont help when checking manually. IMO.

Comment: Then create a view or a proc with your logic to detect duplicates. Your trigger `UPDATES` the data... if you wan't to report on the data, updating it would skew it. My point was, add a constraint or handle it with the UPSERT before you add another pointless tep (trigger)