# With CTE, compare rows with same ID and updating oldest one to 0 SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

[Asked for the logic yesterday, now I've worked a way around.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54422639/detecting-repeated-records-and-marking-old-ones-with-the-new-record-id)

I have a big table used for reporting (170k~ rows) and many of them are "duplicated" but with updated dates (e.g. old record says `John Doe worked from X to Y` and new one says `John Doe worked from X2 to Y2`).

I want to know which ones are the **old** and **new** so I set a special column storing Boolean values (default `1`) so when I run the CTE I created if there is multiple records with the same ID change the old value to `0`. With this cte I get the **new record deleted** and I'm trying to change the delete part to **update the old record** but I get an error 207 because the column `valid` isn't valid.

Any help with my code it's appreciated.

```
;with cte
    as (select Row_number() over (partition BY id_gen, perpro,valido order by ini desc) RN 
        from tstSolap)
delete from cte
--update cte set valido = 0
where RN > 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CTE somehow knows to identify the rows for the UPDATE or DELETE.

But to actually UPDATE a certain column, then you also need to include it in the CTE.
For a DELETE, that's not a must.

And you could then also just include the other fields you use in that ROW_NUMBER.
That makes it easier to copy the CTE's query, to test it manually before actually doing any changes.

Also, I doubt you actually need `valido` in the `PARTITION BY` to find duplicate (id_gen, perpro) tupples.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT 
   id_gen, perpro, ini, valido,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_gen, perpro ORDER BY ini DESC) RN 
  FROM tstSolap
)
UPDATE CTE
SET valido = 0
WHERE RN > 1
  AND (valido IS NULL OR valido <> 0)
```

Or if you want to correct both 0 or 1

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT 
   id_gen, perpro, ini, valido,
   IIF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_gen, perpro ORDER BY ini DESC) = 1, 1, 0) AS new_valido
  FROM tstSolap
)
UPDATE CTE
SET valido = new_valido
WHERE (valido != new_valido OR valido IS NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!, Do you know If I could compare directly dates `ini` and `fin` on those records instead of ordering by date? I've noticed that on the real db (I'm currently using a test table) there could be cases of new records actually having periods **earlier** than the original record. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That makes me suspect that ini & fin are dates filled by the users.  I would rather use a column that's filled in automatically when the record is inserted. F.e. `CreatedOn datetime default GetDate()`

Comment: That was a super smart approach, gladly the real table has a timestamp for that, I still might have to work parsing dates, marking your answer as correct, thanks!

Comment: @Ali Note the update (I fixed a copy&paste error and added an extra SQL)

Answer (score 1):

Just include that column `valido` in `CTE` :

```
with cte as (
     select s.*,
            Row_number() over (partition BY id_gen, perpro,valido order by ini desc) RN 
     from tstSolap as s
)
update cte 
     set valido = 0
where RN > 1;
```

Comment: Im a SQL newbie, that totally went over my head, thanks for the clarification!. Do you know if I could -instead of ordering rows- compare the registry id? (considering the oldest id will have a value lesser than the newest one).